# Apply template on element that does not contain another element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Suppose I have an element x and I want to do something if that element doesn't contain 
another element y, e.g.:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//x">
    <xs:if test="expression to check does not contain y">

    </xs:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 not(y)
```

tests if an element does not have a direct child element y.

Answer (score 0):

**Better use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select = "//x[not(y)]"/>
```

this applies templates on any `x` element that has no `y` element as a child.

In this way, you don't specify any conditional logic inside the selected for execution, matching template(s).

**If by "contain" you mean "has a descendent (not only child), then the above should be specified as**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select = "//x[not(descendant::y)]"/>
```